# how to create jpa entity had join relation using @ResponseBody

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i have two entity member, department. member have to be in a department.

```
public class Member {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private String number;

  @NonNull
  @Column(nullable=false)
  private String name;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="department_number")
  @NonNull
  @JsonIdentityReference
  private Department department;
}

public class Department {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int department_number;

  @NonNull
  @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
  private String name;


  @OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
  @JsonBackReference
  private List<Member> members;
}
```

and my method in controller is this

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, path="/member/")
public ResponseEntity<Member> 
        createMember(@RequestBody Member member) {

  return new ResponseEntity<Member>(
              memberRepository.save(member)
              , HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

when i try this

```
POST localhost:8080/member/
{
    "name": "test",
    "department": {
        "name": "human resource"
    }
}
```

I get this error

```
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException",
"message": "org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : rura6502.tistory.com.domain.Member.department -> rura6502.tistory.com.domain.Department; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : rura6502.tistory.com.domain.Member.department -> rura6502.tistory.com.domain.Department",
"path": "/member/"
```

I know this error because of department parameter. entity cannot recognize 'human resource' without department_number(@Id). and I have to request this structure

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "department": {
    "name": "human resource",
    "department_number": 1
  }
}
```

is there any way to create member using my structure?(without department_number structure. department.name also unique)

Comment: why do you need to use? private String number; ?

Comment: @VK321 i think department.name and department_number is same to recognize each value. so i want that client just have needed value for information to know each row.

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: @VK321 i am using embedded h2 in spring boot and i will use mariaDB

Comment: What do you think about posted answer. Will that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You must use `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` in your parent collection to instruct hibernate to save your child as well.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, name="department_number")
@NonNull
@JsonIdentityReference
private Department department;
```

If you'll be using bi-directional relationship, you have to specify the cascade type in child collection also.

You may also need to fix your `Id` of `Member`

Answer (score 0):

Member object need department object before. So can try this:

```
@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST, path="/member")
public ResponseEntity<Member> createMember(@RequestBody Member member) {

    // Get department name from json
    String deptName = member.getDepartment().getName();

    Department department = null;

    //check if dept already exists
    Department alreadyExistsDepartment = departmentRepository.findByName(deptName);

    if(alreadyExistsDepartment == null){
        Department department1 = new Department();
        department1.setName(deptName);
        department = departmentRepository.save(department1);
    } else{
        department = alreadyExistsDepartment;
    }

    member.setDepartment(department);
    memberRepository.save (member);

   //other code here
}
```

This is the right way to model your entities class:

**Member.java**

```
@Entity
public class Member {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long memberId;

  @NonNull
  @Column(nullable=false)
  private String name;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="department_id")
  private Department department;

  // getters and setters
}
```

**Department.java**

```
@Entity
public class Department {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long departmentId;

  @NonNull
  @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
  private String name;


  @OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
  @JsonBackReference
  private List<Member> members;
  // getters and setters
}
```

**DepartmentRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Long> {

   Department findByName(String name);

}
```